# Testing for NULL in ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

In database; there's 3 columns, `Name`, `CreatedDate` and `UpdatedDate`.
I want to make stored procedure to to get all rows order last update or created date.

Here's my sample code.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN UpdatedDate != null THEN UpdatedDate ELSE CreatedDate END desc
```

But received wrong result. Any Idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When comparing with `null` you need the `is` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name
ORDER BY CASE WHEN UpdatedDate is not null 
              THEN UpdatedDate 
              ELSE CreatedDate 
         END desc
```

or in your case you can just use

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
ORDER BY coalesce(UpdatedDate, CreatedDate) desc
```

Comment: Thanks; Why I didn't think that! Thanks alot.